# CSS/HTML: How to make a left side div responsive that collapse when minimized the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

So I have a two divs that are partitioning the page body, but I need to collapse the left side div when user minimizes the page. And when it click the collapsed side div, it goes back to previous.

html

```
<div class="" style="display:flex; min-height:700px;">
        <div class="left_temp_sider">
            DIV1
        </div>
        <div class="right_temp_sider">
            DIV2
        </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.left_temp_sider{
   min-width: 300px;
   margin-top:70px;
   padding:20px 0px 20px 35px; 
}
.right_temp_sider{
   flex:1;
}
```

[image: This how it looks like]

Comment: show us something you tried?

Comment: try using media queries css

Comment: just use bootstrap

Comment: are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jaysingkar no i need to do manual

Comment: What exactly do you mean by minimize? When the page is under a certain width/height? When the browser window is minimized to the taskbar? If the latter, what do you need this for?

Comment: after implementing Adrians solution, use an on-click to reset min-width back to whatever you want

Comment: @Tobl yes when its on certain width/height

Answer (score 2):

Try media queries: need to reset min-width instead of max-width

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .left_temp_sider{
         min-width: 50px;

    }
}
```

If your viewport width is less than 600px, the CSS rules specified inside `@media` will be applied.